# vscode - Is there a way to manually trigger events?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am running a callback on the `workspace.onWillSaveTextDocument` handler. It provides `vscode.TextDocument` and this is necessary for the work I want to do on this event.

In certain cases, I want to treat other files (that aren't currently open) as if they had just been saved, as well.

It would suffice to be able to create a new instance of `vscode.TextDocument`, but I was unable to figure that out.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
workspace.pretendThisWasSavedJustNow('/path/to/other/file.ts');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work on VSCode and while I don't know your exact use case, I believe you are looking for `workspace.openTextDocument`.

To use the same function for `workspace.onWillSaveTextDocument` and on some other event that your extension triggers, try something like:

```
// Actual save
workspace.onWillSaveTextDocument(e => onDocumentSave(e.document))

// Emulated save
setInterval(() => {
    workspace.openTextDocument('path/to/other/file.ts')
        .then(document => onDocumentSave(document))
}, 5000)

// Common save handling implementation
function onDocumentSave(document: TextDocument) { ... }
```